# Exponential functions acting on n different points give linearly independent values

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, exponential-function

Let $n$ be a positive integer and $x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n}$ be $n$ distinct real numbers. Let $\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2},\cdots,\lambda_{n}$ be $n$ distinct real numbers, and consider the  exponential functions
$$f_{i}(x) = e^{\lambda_{i}x},\quad i=1,2,\cdots,n.$$
Then for $i=1,2,\cdots,n$, define a vector $v_{i}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ as follows:
$$v_{i} = \left(f_{i}(x_{1}),\cdots,f_{i}(x_{n})\right),$$
prove that $v_{1},\cdots,v_{n}$ are linearly independent.

The problem can be translated into a rather analytical form as: the linear combination of $n$ distinct exponential functions can't have $n$ distinct zeros. This can then be solved by induction. In fact, by using the mean-value theorem we can directly reduce it into the $(n-1)$-situation.

However, the original problem looks more like an algebraic one. If the $x_{i}$'s are all positive integers, I believe that it is a purely algebraic problem. So I'm wondering if there is a more algebraic and more natural approach.

Comment: See [this post on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/118225/34894)

Comment: If the $x_i$ are all positive integers, then you can apply [the approach here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3854625/81360)